# What values can be provided to "expandCollapseCuePosition" property in cytoscape.js-expand-collapse library?

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

I'm trying to render this cue Image on the top right corner of the nodes but this property is not taking any values other than "top-left". It does not render anything on providing any other string/function.

The document says it takes in a function but I'm not able to figure out how to use this. I have checked their source code, looked for similar open repos but none to avail.

> ```
>  expandCollapseCuePosition: 'top-left', // default cue position is top left you can specify a function per node too
> ```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You.

After running the below solution provided by sanka:[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can create a function like this.

```
function setCuePosition(e) {
  const { x1, x2, y1, y2, h, w } = e._private.bodyBounds; // use x1, x2, y1, y2, h, w  for make different positions
  return { x: x2, y: y1 };
}

var api = cy.expandCollapse({
  // other options...
  expandCollapseCuePosition: setCuePosition,
});
```

EDIT:
We have to update the position after expanding a node

```
cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.afterexpand", function (e) {
  api.setOption("expandCollapseCuePosition", setCuePosition);
});
```

The above coordinates are suitable for rectangle-shaped nodes. I created an equation to get the position for circle shapes too.

```
function setCuePosition(e) {
  const { x1, x2, y1, y2, h, w } = e._private.bodyBounds;

  // if shape is a circle
  if (w === h) {
    return {
      x: x1 + h / 2 + h / (2 * Math.sqrt(2)),
      y: y1 + h / 2 - h / (2 * Math.sqrt(2)),
    };
  }

  // if shape is a rectangle
  const margin = 10;
  return { x: x2 - margin, y: y1 + margin };
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This works on the top level, but when expanded, the positon is not retained, it is displaying almost to the middle of the group (the expanded container) box.

Comment: @PoornimaT I have updated the answer. could you please check it again 

Comment: This does work in a way, but there's a lot of space between the icon and the node, around 10px I would say.  I think bodyBounds calculate some the margin around the nodes too and that causes this, I think. I have not provided any padding or margin to my nodes.

Comment: @PoornimaT It is not about margins and paddings. The reason is node shape. I have updated the answer again assuming you have a circle shape nodes

Comment: This does not work as expected. Really appreciate taking your time to solve this.  I have attached a screenshot after running this, in the question itself. The cue does not show up on first click whenever I have tried giving a function.

Comment: @PoornimaT Updated the function again, and this works fine for me. Give a value for a margin as you want .